# node-sass-middleware generating undefined .css files

Tags: css, node.js, sass, node-sass

I must say, I'm pretty new to this kind of development, and to this tool, so I might have a noobish mistake.

That said, my problem is:

- I have this in my app.coffee:

  ```
  srcPath = __dirname + '/sass'
  destPath = __dirname + '/public'
  app.use(sassMiddleware({
      src: srcPath,
      dest: destPath,
      debug: true,
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
  }));
  ```

  app.use(express.static(path.join( __dirname, 'public')));
- I also have a simple .scss file in my /sass directory:

  ```
  .message {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #333;
  }
  ```

just for testing purposes.

- When I request the .css files, they get generated, but they are all "undefined".

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this line on the package.json devDependencies:

```
"gulp-sass": "^1.3.3",
```